# Implementation of Naive Bayes - accuracy issues

Tags: python, machine-learning

**EDIT: The correct version of the code which works can be found at :** 
https://github.com/a7x/NaiveBayes-Classifier

I used data from [openClassroom](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex6/ex6.html) and started working on a small version of Naive Bayes in Python. Steps were the usual training and then prediction . I have a few questions and want to know why the accuracy is quite bad.

1. For training, I calculated the log likelihood by the formula  :

   > log( P ( word  | spam ) +1 ) /( spamSize + vocabSize .)

   My question is: why did we add the `vocabSize` in this case :( and is this the correct way of going about it? Code used is below:

   ```
   #This is for training.     Calculate all probabilities and store them in a vector. Better to store it in a file  for easier access 
   from __future__ import division
   import sys,os
   ''' 
   1. The spam and non-spam is already 50%  . So they by default are 0.5
   2. Now we need to calculate probability of each word    , in spam and non-spam separately
     2.1  we can make two dictionaries, defaultdicts basically,  for spam and non-spam 
     2.2 When time comes to calculate probabilities, we just need to substitute values
   '''
   from collections import *
   from math import *

   spamDict = defaultdict(int)
   nonspamDict = defaultdict(int)
   spamFolders = ["spam-train"]
   nonspamFolders = ["nonspam-train"]
   path = sys.argv[1] #Base path
   spamVector = open(sys.argv[2],'w') #WRite all spam values into this 
   nonspamVector = open(sys.argv[3],'w') #Non-spam values

   #Go through all files in spam and  iteratively add values
   spamSize = 0
   nonspamSize = 0
   vocabSize = 264821
   for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(path,spamFolders[0])):
       data = open(os.path.join(path,spamFolders[0],f),'r')

       for line in data:
           words = line.split(" ")
           spamSize = spamSize + len(words)
           for w in words:
               spamDict[w]+=1

   for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(path,nonspamFolders[0])):
       data = open(os.path.join(path,nonspamFolders[0],f),'r')
       for line in data:
           words = line.split(" ")
           nonspamSize = nonspamSize + len(words)
           for w in words:

               nonspamDict[w]+=1
   logProbspam = {}
   logProbnonSpam = {} #This is to store the log probabilities
   for k in spamDict.keys():
       #Need to calculate P(x | y = 1)

       numerator =  spamDict[k] + 1  # Frequency
       print 'Word',k,' frequency',spamDict[k]
       denominator = spamSize + vocabSize
       p = log(numerator/denominator)
       logProbspam[k] = p
   for k in nonspamDict.keys():
       numerator = nonspamDict[k] + 1 #frequency
       denominator = nonspamSize + vocabSize
       p = log(numerator/denominator)
       logProbnonSpam[k] = p

   for k in logProbnonSpam.keys():
       nonspamVector.write(k+" "+str(logProbnonSpam[k])+"\n")
   for k in logProbspam.keys():
       spamVector.write(k+" "+str(logProbspam[k])+"\n")
   ```
2. For prediction, I just took a mail , split it into words, added all the probabilities, separately for 
   spam/non-spam, and multiplied them by 0.5. Whichever was higher was the class label. Code is below:

   http://pastebin.com/8Y6Gm2my ( Stackoverflow was again playing games for some reason :-/)

**EDIT : I have removed the spam = spam + 1 thing. Instead, I just ignore those words**

Problem : My accuracy is quite bad .  As noted below.

```
    No of files in spam is 130
    No. of spam in  ../NaiveBayes/spam-test  is  53  no. of non-spam 77
    No of files in non-spam is 130
    No. of spam in  ../NaiveBayes/nonspam-test/  is  6  no. of non-spam 124
```

Please tell me where all I am going wrong. I think an accuracy of less than 50% means there must be some glaring error(s) in the implementation.

Comment: You are not doing "naive Bayes", you are doing Bayes with Laplace Smoothing, with "k" (the Laplace Smoothing parameter) equal to 1.  That is why you are adding 1 to the numerator (k) and vocabsize (k * set_size) to the denominator.

Comment: Have you run the above code? Doesn't it give you a math domain error? You need to collect the counts as floats else on division everything will become zero.

Comment: Go to https://www.ai-class.com/home/ and watch the videos on "Machine Learning" (lesson #5) to find out more about Laplace Smoothing and whether it's the right thing to do or not.  There are pros and cons to using it.

Comment: @JimClay: Laplace or Lidstone smoothing is performed in just about every practical implementation of multinomial Naive Bayes.

Comment: I think  the from __future__ import division part took care of the division .  Yeah  I added laplace to make up for the absentees .  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors and bad assumptions in your program - in both parts of it. Here are several.

1. You hardcode into your program the fact that you have the same number of spam and non-spam emails. I'd recommend not to hardcode this assumption. This is not absolutely essential, but in a more general case you will need to remove it.
2. You hadrcode into your program some number that you treat as the vocabulary size. I'd not recommend doing this as this number may change on any modification of the training set. Furthermore, actually it's incorrect. I'd recommend to calculate it during learning.
3. This may be not a mistake, but you seem to have a vocabulary of all the words in the training set. This may be suboptimal; actually the page you refer to recommends to take into account only the top-2500 words over all the emails. However, that's not essential for obtaining correct results - even without this filtering, my implementation is getting only several emails unclassified.
4. You incorrectly account for words that have been observed in spam or non-spam only. The log-probability for them being found in the other subset is not `1` which you add, but `log(1/(spamSize+vocabSize))` or `log(1/(nonspamSize+vocabSize))` depending on its group. This is actually very important - you need to store this probability with your data for the program to function correctly.
5. You do not ignore words never observed in the training set. Actually these may be treated in different ways, but you should take them into account.
6. Due to incorrect indentation in the prediction function, you predict using not the whole message, but only the first line of the message. Just a programming bug.

**Update**. You have fixed 6. Also 1 is not strictly nessesary to fix while you're working with this dataset, as well as 3 is not required.
Your modification did not correctly fix either 4 or 5. First, if the word has never been observed in some set, the probability of the message in it should decrease. Ignoring the word is not a good idea, you need to account for it as a highly unprobable one.
Second, your current code is asymmetric as the word being absent in spam cancels the check for non-spam (but not the other way). If you need to do nothing in an exception handler, use `pass`, not `continue`, as the latter immediately goes to the next `for w in words:` iteration.
The problem number 2 is also still in place - the vocabulary size you use does not match the real one. It must be the number of different words observed in the training set, not the total number of words in all the messages together.

Comment: 1. I hard-coded it as it actually had an equal no. of spam and non-spam

Comment: 2. I will take only 2500  as suggested on the site then 3. I changed the indentation but the answer has remained the same sadly :(  I will modify the accounting for words found in spam/non-spam only. Thanks.

Comment: Currently the primary problem seems to be the one number 4. If you've never seen some word in spam, it makes it highly unprobable and you need to penalize this probability heavily instead of increasing it by adding one.

Comment: I am guessing what you mean to say is that the part where I do numerator  = spamDict[k]+1 should be changed to spamdict[k]+log(1/(number))  ??

Comment: No, you're wrong. The offending line is `spamP = spamP + 1` in the `except` clause which is in the `predict` function. And the one about non-spam too.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet. Since the last time I posted itself, I was ignoring words which were not part of that group. I have posted link to the updated code. Please have a look

Comment: I've updated the answer according to the new code... it's still not OK, there are multiple problems.

Comment: Thanks ! I will work on it and get back asap ! Will post here :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I changed the code to consider only the first 2500 words , and also changed the vocab size. And managed to get the correct answer ! So, thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

Here's at least one of the errors you're making: you're storing log-probabilities in your model file (as you should), but then in the prediction code you're pretending that they are straight probabilities:

```
totalSpamP = spamP * 0.5
```

should be

```
totalSpamP = spamP + math.log(0.5)
```

Also, I don't get what this line is doing:

```
spamP = spamP + 1
```

It seems to be making up for a feature not found in the spam part of the training set, but those words should simply be ignored. Right now, it's adding *e* (`exp(1)`) to a probability, which by definition is invalid.

(As an aside, I just tried classification on this training set with [my own implementation of Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/naive_bayes.html) and got 97.6% accuracy, so that's the figure you should be aiming at :)

Comment: Hi , Let me  make the changes and get back to you ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Btw , why do we add the vocab size ? Is laplace smoothing the reason behind adding it ?

Comment: Yes the spamP = spamP + 1 was adding 1 to it, which now I have removed.

Comment: Hi, I have  made the changes you suggested. The accuracy has definitely improved, atleast for the non-spam case , but the spam case remains the same :( What other changes should be made ?

Comment: Hi, there was a small mistake due to which the non-spam accuracy was going wrong.  Its fixed. But the spam one is still horribly wrong :(